# Why do I keep getting WhereChain Query due to scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So i'm trying to create a scope that takes two variables, (current_user, other_user) and seperate the messages between the two based off of sender_id and receiver_id (my foreign_keys).

I've used the following before on a project, and it worked well:

```
scope :between, -> (me, other) { Message.where{((:sender_id == my{me.id}) & (:receiver_id     == my{other.id})) | ((:sender_id == my{other.id}) & (:receiver_id == my{me.id}))}}
```

However, on my current project, I use the same thing, and it's doing two things.

1: After binding.pry it provides this response.

```
[1] pry(#<ConversationsController>)> @messages
   Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"
 => #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00000106d83c98
   @scope=
   [#<Message id: 1, title: nil, body: "Message 1", sender_id: 11,        receiver_id: 1, created_at: "2014-05-20 19:29:34", updated_at: "2014-05-20 19:29:34">,
    #<Message id: 2, title: nil, body: "Message 2", sender_id: 1, receiver_id: 11, created_at: "2014-05-20 19:30:15", updated_at: "2014-05-20 19:30:15">,
    #<Message id: 3, title: nil, body: "radda?", sender_id: 1, receiver_id: 109, created_at: "2014-05-20 19:30:39", updated_at: "2014-05-20 19:30:39">]>
```

As you can see above, it's combining all user id's, not just the sender and receiver.  So all users receive all messages.  And then, I keep getting this WhereChain Error.

```
#<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00000107f99ea0>
```

Please help me understand what I may be doing wrong, or what I could do right.  Thank you.

Comment: You do have squeel gem in the second project as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have `squeel` gem installed in your current project and the syntax you are using requires it. In Rails 3 you would receive an error `wrong number of arguments 0 for 1`, however in rails 4 you can call `where` without any params (so you can call `not`). The block you passed has been ignored and `WhereChain` object is returned.

Note that `squeel` is no longer maintained. Use with care.

Comment: You can still use it, but you need to keep in mind it might not work as expected with newer versions of rails. Eventually write this query withou sqeel, like @UriAgassi suggested.

Comment: Thanks, I realized when you said squeel that you were right.  I remembered someone telling me to use squeel to write this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
scope :between, -> (me, other) { where(['(sender_id = :me and receiver_id = :other) or (sender_id = :other and receiver_id = :me)', {me: me.id, other: other.id}])}
```

Comment: Could we get rid of `Message` within the scope? It kills its usability.

Comment: @BroiSatse I removed it, though I think you had the right point there regarding the squeel gem... I wondered about the strange syntax

Comment: I wish I could give you both a check.  However he more or less answered why it wasn't working.  Whereas you gave me a great way to write it out without error.  So thank you so very much for this.  I will be sure to upvote some more of your stuff to make up for the lack of check.